# テーブルに対して行選択するコードを書きたい

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

テーブルに対して行選択しているファイルをダウンロードボタンでダウンロードできるものを考えています。
まず行選択できるコードの書き方が分からなくて悩んでいます。行選択できるようにするにはどういったコードを追記すればよろしいでしょうか。
ソースは下記となります。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>ファイルダウンロード</title>

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>ファイルダウンロード画面</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <table border="1" width="500" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"
            bordercolor="#333333">
            <tr>
                <th bgcolor="#EE0000"><font color="#FFFFFF">Ｎｏ</font></th>
                <th bgcolor="#EE0000" width="150"><font color="#FFFFFF">ファイル名</font></th>
                <th bgcolor="#EE0000" width="200"><font color="#FFFFFF">備考</font></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#99CC00" align="right" nowrap>１</td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" width="150">aaa.text</td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" width="200">-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#99CC00" align="right" nowrap>２</td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" width="150">bbb.text</td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" width="200">-</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="padding-top: 10px">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">ダウンロード</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

class(dataとfilename)とattribute(flag)を付加してサンプルを書いてみました。
色々な方法がありますが、こんな感じでしょうか。
選択行を取得ボタンの処理結果はconsole.logへ出力しました。

```js
$(function(){
            $('.data').on("click",function(){
                var no = $('.data').index(this);
                    if((no < $('.data').length) && (no > 0)){
                        var flag = $('.data').eq(no).attr("flag");
                        if(flag == "0"){
                            $('.data').eq(no).css("background-color","greenyellow");
                            $('.data').eq(no).attr("flag","1");
                        }else{
                            $('.data').eq(no).css("background-color","#ffffff");
                            $('.data').eq(no).attr("flag","0");
                        }
                    }
                }
            );

            $('#button').on("click",function(){
                    for(var i=0;i<$('.data').length;i++){
                        var flag = $('.data').eq(i).attr("flag");
                        if(flag == "1"){
                            console.log($('.filename').eq(i).text());
                        }
                    }
                }
            );


            $('.data').css("background-color","#ffffff");
            $('.data').attr("flag","0");


        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button id="button">選択行を取得</button>
<table border="1" width="500" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" bordercolor="#333333">
    <tr class="data">
        <th bgcolor="#EE0000">
            <font color="#FFFFFF">Ｎｏ</font>
        </th>
        <th class="filename" bgcolor="#EE0000" width="150">
            <font color="#FFFFFF">ファイル名</font>
        </th>
        <th bgcolor="#EE0000" width="200">
            <font color="#FFFFFF">備考</font>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data">
        <td align="right" nowrap>１</td>
        <td class="filename" valign="top" width="150">aaa.text</td>
        <td valign="top" width="200">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data">
        <td align="right" nowrap>２</td>
        <td class="filename" valign="top" width="150">bbb.text</td>
        <td valign="top" width="200">-</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

難しいことは考えず、行を選択しているというチェックボックス列を追加してやればよいかと思われます。
その後選択されているcheckboxの値を取り出し、よしなにしてやればよいかと。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ファイルダウンロード</title>
    <script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getSelected() {
            var checkedValues = $('.checkboxes:checked').map(function(index, checkbox) {
                return $(checkbox).val();
            }).toArray();
            console.log(checkedValues);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getSelected()">選択行を取得</button>
    <table border="1" width="500" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" bordercolor="#333333">
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#EE0000">
            </th>
            <th bgcolor="#EE0000">
                <font color="#FFFFFF">Ｎｏ</font>
            </th>
            <th bgcolor="#EE0000" width="150">
                <font color="#FFFFFF">ファイル名</font>
            </th>
            <th bgcolor="#EE0000" width="200">
                <font color="#FFFFFF">備考</font>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#99CC00" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="aaa.text" /></td>
            <td bgcolor="#99CC00" align="right" nowrap>１</td>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" width="150">aaa.text</td>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" width="200">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#99CC00" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="bbb.text" /></td>
            <td bgcolor="#99CC00" align="right" nowrap>２</td>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" width="150">bbb.text</td>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" width="200">-</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。勉強になります。チェックボックスではなくテーブルのうちの1行を選択状態にしてボタン押下でダウンロードできるような形も知りたいのですがどういったコードを書けばいいか分かりますでしょうか。

Comment: iOSなどスマホのリストのようなものを想定しているのでしたらhtmlにはありませんので、ライブラリを探すか自作する必要があります。trにonclickを仕込みselectedRowNumberを取得し、cssクラスを追加、削除することで選択状態にあるように見せかける、と言った具合でしょうか